# azure data factory start pipeline different from starting job

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting crazy on this issue, I am running an Azure data factory V1, I need to schedule a copy job every week from 01/03/2009 through 01/31/2009, so I defined this schedule on the pipeline:

```
    "start": "2009-01-03T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2009-01-31T00:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
```

monitoring the pipeline, the data factory schedule on these date:

```
12/29/2008
01/05/2009
01/12/2009
01/19/2009
01/26/2009
```

instead of this wanted schedule:

```
01/03/2009
01/10/2009
01/17/2009
01/24/2009
01/31/2009
```

why the starting date defined on the pipeline doesn't correspond to the schedule date on the monitor?

Many thanks!

Here is the JSON Pipeline:

```
{
"name": "CopyPipeline-blob2datalake",
"properties": {
    "description": "copy from blob storage to datalake directory structure",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL",
            "typeProperties": {
                "scriptPath": "script/dat230.usql",
                "scriptLinkedService": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
                "degreeOfParallelism": 5,
                "priority": 100,
                "parameters": {
                    "salesfile": "$$Text.Format('/DAT230/{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}.txt', Date.StartOfDay (SliceStart))",
                    "lineitemsfile": "$$Text.Format('/dat230/dataloads/{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}/factinventory/fact.csv', Date.StartOfDay (SliceStart))"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "InputDataset-dat230"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OutputDataset-dat230"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "01:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "retry": 1
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 7
            },
            "name": "DataLakeAnalyticsUSqlActivityTemplate",
            "linkedServiceName": "AzureDataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2009-01-03T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2009-01-11T00:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "edxlearningdf_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
}
```

and here the datasets:

```
{
"name": "InputDataset-dat230",
"properties": {
    "structure": [
        {
            "name": "Date",
            "type": "Datetime"
        },
        {
            "name": "StoreID",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "StoreName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "ProductID",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "ProductName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "Color",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "Size",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "Manufacturer",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "OnHandQuantity",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "OnOrderQuantity",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "SafetyStockQuantity",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "UnitCost",
            "type": "Double"
        },
        {
            "name": "DaysInStock",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "MinDayInStock",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "MaxDayInStock",
            "type": "Int64"
        }
    ],
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "Source-BlobStorage-dat230",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "*.txt.gz",
        "folderPath": "dat230/{year}/{month}/{day}/",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "columnDelimiter": "\t",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true
        },
        "partitionedBy": [
            {
                "name": "year",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "WindowStart",
                    "format": "yyyy"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "month",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "WindowStart",
                    "format": "MM"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "day",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "WindowStart",
                    "format": "dd"
                }
            }
        ],
        "compression": {
            "type": "GZip"
        }
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 7
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
}
}

{
"name": "OutputDataset-dat230",
"properties": {
    "structure": [
        {
            "name": "Date",
            "type": "Datetime"
        },
        {
            "name": "StoreID",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "StoreName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "ProductID",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "ProductName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "Color",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "Size",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "Manufacturer",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "OnHandQuantity",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "OnOrderQuantity",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "SafetyStockQuantity",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "UnitCost",
            "type": "Double"
        },
        {
            "name": "DaysInStock",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "MinDayInStock",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        {
            "name": "MaxDayInStock",
            "type": "Int64"
        }
    ],
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureDataLakeStore",
    "linkedServiceName": "Destination-DataLakeStore-dat230",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "txt.gz",
        "folderPath": "dat230/dataloads/{year}/{month}/{day}/factinventory/",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "columnDelimiter": "\t"
        },
        "partitionedBy": [
            {
                "name": "year",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "WindowStart",
                    "format": "yyyy"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "month",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "WindowStart",
                    "format": "MM"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "day",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "WindowStart",
                    "format": "dd"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Day",
        "interval": 7
    },
    "external": false,
    "policy": {}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the time slices for the datasets and there activity.

The pipeline schedule (badly named) only defines the start and end period in which any activities can use to provision and run there time slices.

ADFv1 doesn't use a recursive schedule like the SQL Server Agent. Each execution has to be provisioned at an interval on the time line (the schedule) you create.

For example, if you pipeline start and end is for 1 year. But your dataset and activity has a frequency of monthly and interval of 1 month you will only get 12 executions of the whatever is happening.

Apologies, but the concept of time slices is a little difficult to explain if you aren't already familiar. Maybe read this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ukdataplatform/2016/05/03/demystifying-activity-scheduling-with-azure-data-factory/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Would you share with us the json for the datasets and the pipeline? It would be easier to help you having that.

In the meanwhile, check if you are using "style": "StartOfInterval" at the scheduler property of the activity, and also check if you are using an offset.

Cheers!